# How much time would it take to test all possible encryption keys?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

My assignment was to finish the code to encrypt and decrypt text, and answer the question:

Assuming that we can test 1 billion encryption keys per second, how many years would it take to test all possible 256-bit encryption keys?

I don't understand how to solve the problem because I don't understand how you are supposed to know how many encryption keys you are testing. Are you testing 26 encryption keys because that is how many letters in the alphabet? Wouldn't that be significantly less than one second- not even close to a year? Does the "256-bit" part affect the answer?

I am unsure whether the code is helpful to answer the question, but in case it is, this is it (this code wouldn't work if the text inputted contains an x, y, or z):

```
ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
KEY = 3;


runCaeserCipher(KEY);

function runCaeserCipher(key){

// ask your user for the message to be encrypted.
var message = prompt("What text would you like to encrypt?");
message = message.toUpperCase(); //make sure all characters are uppercase
// create secretMessage by passing message through the encrypt function
var secretMessage = encrypt(message,key);
console.log("The encrypted message is: " + secretMessage + "\n");

// decrypt the secret message by passing secretMessage through the decrypt     function
var decryptedMessage = decrypt(secretMessage,key);


// check to see if the original and decrypted messages are the same
if (message == decryptedMessage){
    console.log("You successfully decoded the message!");
}
else{
    console.log("Something went wrong...");
    console.log("Your original message was \"" + message + "\", but your decrypted message is \"" + decryptedMessage + "\".");
}
}


function encrypt(data, key){
// write your code to encrypt the function here
// HINT: use indexOf to search for the index of a specific character within     the ALPHABET
var encryptedMessage = "";

//look at every character in the message
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    //save whatever is 3 spaces after the current char
    encryptedMessage += data.indexOf(i+3);
}   
return encryptedMessage;
}
function decrypt(data, key){
var decryptedMessage = "";

// write your code to decrypt the function here
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    //save whatever is 3 spaces after the current char
    decryptedMessage += data.indexOf(i-3);
}   
return decryptedMessage;
}
```

Comment: A 256-bit key means there are `Math.pow(2, 256)` different possible keys.

Comment: You need irresponsible amounts of performance to solve `1.1579208923731619542357098500868790785326998466564056 × 10^77` different keys in just years. It would need multiple of age of universe in a blackhole horizon(so it computes before universe explodes).

Comment: 26 encryption keys? Sure, if all the encryption keys are a single letter (which clearly wouldn't be any sort of encryption at all, much less useful). Did you even think about it for a second before you wrote that?

Answer (score 2):

256-bits is referring to the length of the key, i.e. it has 256 bits of information. A bit can either be 0 or 1.

If we have two bits, we can represent 2^2 numbers:

```
0 0 = 0
0 1 = 1
1 0 = 2
1 1 = 3
```

As we increase the number of bits, the numbers we can represent increase by a power of 2. We can represent **2^n** possible numbers for **n** bits.

So in your case, a 256-bit key can represent `2^256` distinct values.

For your code, a caesar cipher is a shift cipher that shifts values by a certain amount. The key is how much the alphabet has been shifted, so 26 possible keys. Very small. All you need to do is test every possible key until you get the same value back.

Answer (score 1):

If there are 256 different bits, then this means that for each one there is two possibilities.  Just following this logic, we can clearly see that there are 2^256 different possibilities that a computer would have to go through.  Using your measurement of 1 billion encryption keys per second, that is about 3 * 10^60 years that it would take to decode all of these possibilities, which is more than 10^50 times the age of the universe.  It is because of this that it is simply impossible to decrypt 256-bit keys.  This also explains why it is so much more effective to have 256-bit keys than 128 bit keys.  128-bit keys have 2^128 possibilities, whereas 256-bit keys have 2^256 bit keys.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: So a 128 bit key would only take about 10^22 years, definitely not secure enough, right?  Oh wait, maybe 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years is enough and 128 bits is all that is needed.

Comment: There is a lot of confusing terminology in this answer... you don't "decrypt" keys?  And suggesting that 256-bit keys are more "effective" than 128-bit keys is very misleading.

Comment: Answering "Why are 256-bit keys used?" 1. They are available and no more difficult or costly to use. 2. People think they are more secure but they really aren't, see point 4. 3. There are certain government security levels that require them, see point 1. 4. In-case (a big if) quantum computers of sufficient capability become available and at an acceptable cost, then 256 bit AES keys are reduced to a 128 bit security level.